# React Component behaving unexpectedly after implementing audio and search functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have trying to figure out why my component is not working as expected.

The below code creates a list of word cards and each card will play audio when clicked.

There is also a search function to filter out the cards.

However, I find that these two functions do not work together.  After searching, sometimes, I  could not get the audio working.  The audio part works fine without any searching.

I am getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: myAudio.current is null
    handlePlayAudio WordsList.js:45
```

So I am guessing when I type in the search, something is causing `myAudio.current` to become null.  The trouble is, sometimes it works but sometimes it doen't!

Does anyone know what is going on and how to fix it?

WordsList.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
// import { Link } from "gatsby"
// import slugify from "slugify"

import styled from "styled-components"

const WordsList = ({ words = [] }) => {
  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("")

  const myAudio = useRef("")

  const filteredWords = words.filter(word => {
    return (
      word.english.toLowerCase().includes(searchField) ||
      word.japanese.toLowerCase().includes(searchField) ||
      word.romaji.toLowerCase().includes(searchField)
    )
  })

  const handleSearchChange = event => {
    const searchField = event.target.value.toLowerCase()
    setSearchField(searchField)
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div className="search-container">
        <input
          className="search-box"
          type="search"
          placeholder="search english, japanese, or romaji"
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="wrapper">
        {filteredWords.map(word => {
          const { id, english, japanese, romaji, image, audio } = word

          const pathToImage = getImage(image)
          const audioUrl = audio.file.url

          const handlePlayAudio = () => {
            myAudio.current.src = `http:${audioUrl}`
            myAudio.current.play()
          }

          return (
            <div
              className="card"
              onClick={handlePlayAudio}
              onKeyDown={handlePlayAudio}
              key={id}
            >
              <audio ref={myAudio} src={`http:${audio.file.url}`} />
              {console.log(audio)}
              {/*<Link key={id} to={`/${slug}`}>*/}
              <GatsbyImage image={pathToImage} className="img" alt={english} />
              <p>
                <b>{english}</b> | {japanese} | {romaji}
              </p>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

const Wrapper = styled.section`
  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  }
  .card {
    color: #333;
  }
  .card:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  p {
    padding-top: 0.6rem;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  .search-container {
    margin: 0 0 1.6rem 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 0;

    ::placeholder {
      /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
      color: #bbb;
      opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder {
      /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
      color: #bbb;
    }

    ::-ms-input-placeholder {
      /* Microsoft Edge */
      color: #bbb;
    }
    text-transform: none;
  }
`

export default WordsList
```

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: I think you have to put your `const filteredWords....` in a `useEffect` that has `searchField` in his dependencies array

Comment: Or you could make a function that take a list of word and a search term and return a filtered list and call it from your jsx, like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-szrmyw?file=src%2FWordList.js

Comment: @coglialoro, can you please teach me know I can use `useEffect` in this case?

Comment: @coglialoro, I tried the second suggestion but it is still the same as before

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz, i'm still puzzled why the previous version didn't work though, i should look into it later. maybe the problem is not what i tought

Comment: I think there is a problem with the ref but i don't have much experience with them. I tried to write a new version that doesn't use them: i created a new `Card` component (that's a good idea in any case) and i'm using a custom made hook to handle the audio. maybe you can give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have come up with an answer.

1. I moved the audio tag out from inside the map
2. onclick get the audio url out
3. Use that url value to update and play the audio tag

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
// import { Link } from "gatsby"
// import slugify from "slugify"

import styled from "styled-components"

const WordsList = ({ words = [] }) => {
  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("")

  const myAudio = useRef("")

  const filteredWords = words.filter(word => {
    return (
      word.english.toLowerCase().includes(searchField) ||
      word.japanese.toLowerCase().includes(searchField) ||
      word.romaji.toLowerCase().includes(searchField)
    )
  })

  const handleSearchChange = event => {
    const searchField = event.target.value.toLowerCase()
    setSearchField(searchField)
  }

  const handleAudio = url => {
    myAudio.current.src = url
    myAudio.current.play()
  }

  // const handleTest = test => console.log(test)

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <audio ref={myAudio} src={""} />

      <div className="search-container">
        <input
          className="search-box"
          type="search"
          placeholder="search english, japanese, or romaji"
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="wrapper">
        {filteredWords.map(word => {
          const { id, english, japanese, romaji, image, audio } = word

          const pathToImage = getImage(image)
          const audioUrl = audio.file.url

          return (
            <div
              className="card"
              onClick={() => handleAudio(audio.file.url)}
              key={id}
            >
              {/*<Link key={id} to={`/${slug}`}>*/}
              <GatsbyImage image={pathToImage} className="img" alt={english} />
              <p>
                <b>{english}</b> | {japanese} | {romaji}
              </p>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

const Wrapper = styled.section`
  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  }
  .card {
    color: #333;
  }
  .card:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  p {
    padding-top: 0.6rem;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  .search-container {
    margin: 0 0 1.6rem 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 0;

    ::placeholder {
      /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
      color: #bbb;
      opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder {
      /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
      color: #bbb;
    }

    ::-ms-input-placeholder {
      /* Microsoft Edge */
      color: #bbb;
    }
    text-transform: none;
  }
`

export default WordsList
```

Comment: Yes, this make sense, i didn't understand how you had a single ref used for multiple audio elements. The filtering works fine this way?

Comment: Nice, i guess i got confused a bit there